# npm login - Registry returned 401 for PUT

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am trying to login to npm by doing `npm login` and entering username, password, and email but I am receiving the following response:

> Registry returned 401 for PUT

npm is saying that I have the incorrect username or password, but I've used the same credentials to login to npmjs.org.

version of node is:
`node -v v6.2.2`

Comment: what is the npm you are using for the login? is it passport?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had an npmrc located at `~/.npmrc` and removed it with `rm ~/.npmrc` and it seemed to fix the issue.

The file contained an authToken in the registry so I suppose it was conflicting with the login?
I'm not sure...

Answer (score 9):

Solutions with `.npmrc` and/or `npm config` were not working for me.
Eventually found the error was for and older npm version with 2fa enabled ([see this thread](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/19088)).

So the following should work

```
npm update npm -g
npm login
```

-- update

On a different machine this didn't work until I updated NodeJS and did `npm i npm -g`.

Answer (score 3):

I guess, that you have overdid registry.
For checking, please, run **npm config get registry**. You should see

```
▶ npm config get registry
https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

If there is not this message, then use **npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/**